# jquery multiplication with broken numbers

Tags: javascript, decimal, multiplication

i coded price * Qty function with jquery but not responding daily prices. They response decimal numbers.

Here is code;

```
 var qty = "3";
 var price = "1.20";
 var res = (qty*price);
 $("#boxres").html(res);
```

They result 3.5999999999999996

i want to only 3.6
how can i fix it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: no this is different but same base

Comment: Are you trying to round the number? Also, the only jQuery in your code is the last line, and has nothing to do with your actual question or the answer.

Comment: lol, i solved with toFixed(1) but round not solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$("#boxres").html(res.toFixed(1));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dfz0bj3z/

Answer (score 2):

Store things in pennies:

```
var qty = 3;
var cost = 120;
var res = cost * qty;
var res_str = '£'+Math.floor(res / 100)+'.'+(res %100).toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Math.round

```
var res = (Math.round((qty*price)*10)/10).toFixed(2);
```

Edit to force to the 100th. Thanks dave.